# ClassCastException VectorDrawable cannot be cast to Animatable

Tags: java, android, xml, vector, android-animation

I want to animate vector drawable 
switch_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="40"
android:viewportHeight="40"
android:width="22dp"
android:height="22dp">
<path
    android:name="switch_circle"
    android:pathData="M5 20A15 15 0 1 0 35 20A15 15 0 1 0 5 20M10 20A10 10 0 1 1 30 20A10 10 0 1 1 10 20"
    android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
</vector>
```

When i start animation, it throws class cast exception.
All tutorial says that it must work properly, but it doesn't.
I dont know why.

```
   AppCompatImageButton switchCircle = (AppCompatImageButton)    view.findViewById(R.id.switchButtonCircle);
            Drawable drawable = switchCircle.getDrawable();                    
                ((Animatable) drawable).start();
```

switch_circle_animated_vector.xml

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:drawable="@drawable/switch_circle" >
<target
    android:name="switch_circle"
    android:animation="@anim/filling" />

</animated-vector>
```

filling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
android:duration="500"
android:propertyName="pathData"
android:valueFrom="M5 20A15 15 0 1 0 35 20A15 15 0 1 0 5 20M10 20A10 10 0 1 1 30 20A10 10 0 1 1 10 20"
    android:valueTo="M5 20A15 15 0 1 0 35 20A15 15 0 1 0 5 20M0 20A0 0 0 1 1 30 20A0 0 0 1 1 0 20"
    android:valueType="pathType" />
</set>
```

image button

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/switchButtonCircle"
            android:background="#0025272a"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/switch_circle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/switchButton"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/switchButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp" />
```

stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.Animatable
                                                                            at com.plorial.telegramcamera.CameraPreviewFragment$1.onClick(CameraPreviewFragment.java:65)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: you need `AnimatedVectorDrawable` to call `start()` method, not `VectorDrawable`

Comment: @pslink
AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat drawableCompat = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(getActivity(), R.drawable.switch_circle_animated_vector);

                drawableCompat.start();

It works without exceptions, but doesn't animate

Comment: because it is not attached to your view

Comment: @pskink use this switchCircle.setImageDrawable(drawableCompat.getCurrent());
                drawableCompat.start(); and it works. Thank you)

Comment: `drawableCompat.getCurrent()`? what is it?

Comment: returns current drawable

Comment: simple `switchCircle.setImageDrawable(drawableCompat)` does not work?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `class cast exception` always call the `start()` method like this:

```
if (drawable instanceof Animatable)
{
    ((Animatable) drawable).start();
}
```

Comment: This will get rid of the exception, but it will not solve his problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem?